# Lisp void-variable error when evaluating function

Tags: lisp, elisp

I'm trying to learn Lisp (elisp, actually), and I tried writing the following function as an exercise Project Euler [Problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2)

```
(defun sumfib (n fn1 fn2 sum)
  "Calculate Fibonacci numbers up to 4,000,000 and sum all the even ones"
  (if (< 4000000 (+ fn1 fn2))
      sum
    (if (equal n 3)
        (sumfib 1 (+ fn1 fn2) fn1 (+ sum (+fn1 fn2)))
      (sumfib (+ n 1) (+ fn1 fn2) fn1 sum)))
```

When I evaluate it I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable fn1)
  (+ fn1 fn2)
  (< 4000000 (+ fn1 fn2))
...
```

Why wouldn't it recognize fn1? If I try to put (+ fn1 fn2) before the 'if' it doesn't complain about it there, so why the error here?

Also, I realize the function may not actually be correct, but for now I'm not worried about the logic - I'll figure that out later. For now, I'm only interested in understanding this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this solves your problem (I don't have an elisp interpreter handy), but you're missing a right paren. There should be one at the end of the first 'if' statement, after 'sum'.

```
  (if (< 4000000 (+ fn1 fn2))
      sum)
```

instead of:

```
 (if (< 4000000 (+ fn1 fn2))
      sum
```

I also think there might be some other issues in there.

Comment: Ooh, I am missing a parenthesis... It's not after the first 'if' though, as that's supposed to be and 'if-else'. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm used to Scheme, which does things a bit differently. Glad I was at least somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need an extra close parenthesis at the end of your function.
2. You need a space in the first clause of the second if: `(+fn1 fn2)` should be `(+ fn1 fn2)`. ELisp otherwise reads it as passing `fn2` to a function named `+fn1`.

Couple of other style issues:

1. A `cond` is a lot easier to read than nested ifs, especially using ELisp indentation style.
2. `=` is the normal predicate used for comparing numbers, not `equal`. Although `equal` will work, it looks funny to the reader. (At least it does in all the other Lisps I know, I could be wrong because I don't know ELisp as well.)

Here's how I'd restructure the function.

```
(defun sumfib (n fn1 fn2 sum)
  "Calculate Fibonacci numbers up to 4,000,000 and sum all the even ones"
  (cond 
    ((< 4000000 (+ fn1 fn2)) sum)
    ((= n 3) (sumfib 1 (+ fn1 fn2) fn1 (+ sum (+ fn1 fn2))))
    (t (sumfib (1+ n) (+ fn1 fn2) fn1 sum))))
```

I ran it, and it returns an answer, but I don't know if it's right according to the project euler specification.